# jQuery to check which div is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to develop a wizard, so I show "row" class each time as one of the wizard page. Here I want to determine which is my div that is currently visible and if visible I can make all other divs hidden and show the second div and so on..

I want to get the index of div which is currently visible.

I have some code like this:

```js
(each time when next button or prev btn is pressed)
var divs = $('.wiz>div');
divs.hide().first().show(); //initial page
//get current index if one the go to next

//index = ??

divs.hide();
divs.eq(index++).show();
```

```html
<div class="wiz">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">

        </div>
        <div class="col s6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">

        </div>
        <div class="col s6">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my HTML file

```
    <div class="wiz">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            block 1
        </div>
        <div class="col s6">
            block 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
            block 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s6">
            block 4
        </div>
        <div class="col s6">
            block 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          block 6
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btn_prev">Prev</button>
<button id="btn_next">Next</button>
```

And this is my javascript code

```
    $(function() {
  //console.log("I'm ready!")
  var divs = $('.wiz>div');
  var index = 0;
  var length = divs.length;

  // initialize
  showHideBlock(divs, index);

  $('#btn_prev').click(function() {
    index = performClick(index, false, length);
    showHideBlock(divs, index);
  });

  $('#btn_next').click(function() {
    index = performClick(index, true, length)
    showHideBlock(divs, index);
  });

});

performClick = function(index, next, length) {
  if (next && index < (length - 1)) return index + 1;

  if (!next && index > 0) return index - 1;

  return index;
}

showHideBlock = function(elt, index) {
  elt.hide();
  elt.eq(index).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try

```
$(element).is(":visible");
```

and put it in an `if` statement? You can do this to test whether an element is visible or not, and because you want to hide the other divs, you could do

```
$(element).css({display: 'none'});
```

which I'm sure you already know how to do.

Check out this `.is()` [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/is/) for more info.